# Selling options to myself... which law does this violate?

Tags: united-states, investing, options, ira

If I sell a covered call from my IRA well above market value and use a separate account to buy the call, I've effectively added money to my IRA beyond the IRA's annual limit. (I can ensure I'm buying my own option by selling an outlandish option with no other participants.)

I'm certainly breaking a law somewhere... but which one?

Comment: When you enter an order, to buy at a crazy high price, how will you be certain your other account is the counter Party? I’d be happy to sell you anything way above market price.

Comment: You can sell a call at a price point and date where no other calls are being sold. Then make sure there's only one ask (at your price) before you buy from the other account.

Comment: In my answer, I interpreted "well above market value" as referring to the call's *strike* in relation to the underlying. If instead this means that the call is traded well above *its* market value, then in some ways the question makes more sense

Comment: How does stuffing extra money into an IRA, with no deduction, but tax due on withdrawal, benefit you?

Comment: Ah... right.

That's a good point.It would only be beneficial if I though my tax bracket would be very high between now and retirement, but low otherwise, which allows the IRA growth's tax to be deferred until retirement.

Comment: @nanoman Yes, I meant that the call is traded well above market value. The strike price may also be absurdly high (to ensure no one else is trading it), but it's the option price that really matters. I should have clarified the question better.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - Selling above market value is the hard part of the equation so that would be the first order. You wouldn't have the opportunity to sell you  way above market price.  If it's marketable, either someone overpays for the call or the order sits there and he gets to buy it from himself in the second account.

Comment: @Todd Taddler - For the majority of the population. one's tax bracket would be higher before retirement.  That's all fine and dandy if the call expires.  If assigned, not so much.

Comment: I presume you are able to take the loss in the taxable acct? This was the goal?

Comment: Yes, take the loss in the taxable account to add more (post-tax) money to your IRA beyond the IRS limit. I should clarify that I don't actually want to do this, but I was curious about what was in place to prevent it. (Otherwise, why have the post-tax IRA limit to begin with?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my other answer, I interpreted "well above market value" as referring to the call's *strike* in relation to the underlying. If instead this means that the call is traded well above *its* market value, then in some ways the question makes more sense. But the problem is that every option that is listed on an exchange, to my knowledge, has a market maker who maintains a bid and ask at all times. So your sell order is hidden, and your buy order is filled at the market maker's ask, unless you choose a price *below* the ask.

More generally, for assets that are not exchange-traded, selling or contributing an asset to one's own IRA at an unfair price would fall under *self-dealing*. This is subject to [controversy](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-campaign-romney-ira/how-did-romneys-ira-grow-so-big-idUSTRE80N04E20120124) regarding what is an unfair price.

Comment: " Any investment made by your IRA must be considered an arm's length transaction." Usually this is referenced when buying a house from yourself or a relative. But it seems it would also apply when buying an option from yourself, especially at a price above market value.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't getting a free lunch (regardless of whether you buy the "same" contract), because the transaction is not guaranteed to transfer money into the IRA. If the call has value, it is because there is some probability that the stock will rise above the strike, in which case you have capped the gains that would otherwise have occurred in the IRA, and effectively transferred money *out* of the IRA (to the long option account).

If you are so sure that the option will expire worthless, why bother buying it? Why not just do the covered write in the IRA and call that a "free contribution"? It's not -- it's just a choice of investment strategy with the IRA assets. People can and do get "free money" this way with *high probability*, but not 100%, and the losses are a doozy.

Comment: The idea is to set the price of a worthless option well above the market price, ensure it's the only one for sale at that strike price and date, then buy it from another account. I'm sure it's illegal, but I haven't been able to find where.

Comment: "If the call has value, it is because there is some probability that the stock will rise above the strike" If the strike has value *in a well established market*. The OP is asking "What if I manipulate the market price?"

Answer (score 0):

"Well above market value" isn't clear.  You can sell your call at any strike price that you want.

However, to sell a fat  premium, you have to be the best ask and that is only possible if the call's B/A is *very* wide (market disinterest) and you place your sell order one increment below the best  ask price (some options trade in 1 cent increments, others in 5 cent increments).   I could effect this sell/buy transaction in less than two seconds but though insignificant, there's still two seconds of exposure. So let's say it's 99.99% probable of trading with yourself. Value has no relevance here because you are bypassing the auction which determines option value relative to option pricing  variables.

If NBBO is tight then your high sell price (above best ask) will be on the order book but will not be actionable.

If you succeed at self trading, ignoring commissions, you will transfer money (without risk) to your IRA account.  But that doesn't necessarily mean success.  There are two possibilities:

1) The call expires worthless and you have a gain in your IRA account which will be taxed at lower rates later on.  The non sheltered loss on the call benefits you more because you are in a higher tax bracket now.  I surmise that this is the germ of an idea in your question.

2) The underlying rises and the call is ITM at expiration.  Your IRA position is assigned and you lose the stock  at the strike (plus premium) but your non sheltered call leads to a gain, possibly large. In essence, you have shifted gain from the IRA to your taxable account with the higher tax rate.  Oops.

"Which law does this violate?"

Prior to the late 90's, selling stock "short against the box" was allowed.  This strategy involved taking a short position when you have a capital gain in a long position, locking in the gain until you  unwind the position in the new year, delaying  taxation and obtaining over a  year of full use of the capital.  It's now a violation that complicates your tax return

"Short against the box"  definitely applies to equities.  I believe it also applies to options but I'm not 100% sure.  If it does, that's the law that you are violating.